# What does CQ NM mean in FT8?

Tags: ft8, wsjt-x

I saw someone on 20m FT8 this morning calling "CQ NM". What does NM mean in this context? They followed the NM with their call and grid as usual.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Now that I've seen a few other 2 letter abbreviations, I've figured out it means they're looking for a contact in New Mexico.

Comment: +1. I think you are exactly right. Most likely it is someone who needs NM for a WAS (Worked All States) award.